# Annotations and consumers based on retention

Tags: java, annotations

I am new to annotations and I have been reading this guide:

https://dzone.com/articles/how-annotations-work-java

It states that `@override` has `RetentionPolicy.SOURCE` retention, and those annotations are removed by the compiler on compilation. Though, later it states that and I quote:

> When we are talking about standard annotations like @Override, the JVM
>   is the consumer and it works at the bytecode level.

I do not get how the JVM could consume this annotation when it was removed by the compiler.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what they mean by that. Maybe they meant the Java _compiler_ is the consumer, though that doesn't explain the whole "at the bytecode level". However, the built-in annotations, such as `@Override`, are handled somewhat specially, _I believe_. User-defined annotations, if they're processed at compile time, are typically processed via an [annotation processor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html). As far as I know, `javac` handles the built-in annotations via a different, implementation-specific mechanism.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, Slaw. Does that mean the writer made an error stating that the Virtual Machine handles @Override?

Comment: I would say it's an error on their part, or at the very least a poor choice of words. Especially since very soon after they say: "_`RetentionPolicy.SOURCE` – Discard during the compile. These annotations don’t make any sense after the compile has completed, so they **aren’t written to the bytecode. Examples:  `@Override`**, `@SuppressWarnings`_".

Comment: Thanks a lot, Slaw. Appreciated. I was scratching my head, and I was like maybe my IQ dropped by 20 points or something.